# Flink - Why should I create my own RichSinkFunction instead of just open and close my PostgreSql connection?

Tags: apache-flink

I would like to know why I really need to create my own RichSinkFunction or use JDBCOutputFormat to connect on the database instead of just Create my connection, perform the query and close the connection using the traditional PostgreSQL drivers inside my SinkFunction?

I found many articles telling do to that but does not explain why? What is the difference?

Code example using JDBCOutputFormat,

```
JDBCOutputFormat jdbcOutput = JDBCOutputFormat.buildJDBCOutputFormat()
     .setDrivername("org.postgresql.Driver")
     .setDBUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:1234/test?user=xxx&password=xxx")
     .setQuery(query)
     .setSqlTypes(new int[] { Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR }) //set the types
     .finish();
```

Code example implementing the own RichSinkFunction,

```
public class RichCaseSink extends RichSinkFunction<Case> {

  private static final String UPSERT_CASE = "INSERT INTO public.cases (caseid, tracehash) "
      + "VALUES (?, ?) "
      + "ON CONFLICT (caseid) DO UPDATE SET "
      + "  tracehash=?";

  private PreparedStatement statement;


  @Override
  public void invoke(Case aCase) throws Exception {

    statement.setString(1, aCase.getId());
    statement.setString(2, aCase.getTraceHash());
    statement.setString(3, aCase.getTraceHash());
    statement.addBatch();
    statement.executeBatch();
  }

  @Override
  public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    Connection connection =
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/casedb?user=signavio&password=signavio");

    statement = connection.prepareStatement(UPSERT_CASE);
  }

}
```

why I cannot just use the PostgreSQL driver?

```
public class Storable implements SinkFunction<Activity>{

    @Override
    public void invoke(Activity activity) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        try(Connection connection =
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/casedb?user=signavio&password=signavio")){

        statement = connection.prepareStatement(UPSERT_CASE);

        //Perform the query

        //close connection...
        }
    }

}
```

Does someone know the technical answer to the best practice in Flink? 
Does Implementation of RichSinkFunction or usage of JDBCOutputFormat do something special?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I read these both posts for references, maybe I didn't get the point.
https://tech.signavio.com/2017/postgres-flink-sink
https://bytefish.de/blog/apache_flink_series_4/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well You can use your own `SinkFunction` that will simply use `invoke()` method to open connection and write data and it should work in general. But it's performance will be very, very poor in most cases.

The actual difference between first example and the second example is the fact that in the `RichSinkFunction` you are using `open()` method to open the connection and prepare the statement. This `open()` method is invoked only once when the function is initialized. In the second example you will open the connection to the database and prepare statement inside the `invoke()` method, which is invoked for every element of the input `DataStream`.**You will actually open a new connection for every element in the stream**.

Creating a database connection is expensive thing to do, and it will for sure have terrible performance drawbacks.

Comment: Thank you @DominikWosiński, 

Based on your answer, if I need to save many things in the database, the recommendation is to create my own RichSinkFunction class, to ensure that we will open just one connection with the database and it will be managed by Flink, am I right?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say that it will really be managed by Flink, it will simply allow Flink to open the connection on the initialization of the function. You should generally use this approach no matter how many elements You have to write (well maybe If You had only one or two elements this wouldn't matter that much), since opening and database connection will introduce a delay. It is also worth noting that it will open one connection, but per each instance of the `RichSinkFunction`.